# Return a Folder GUID from a SharePoint Custom Workflow Activity

Tags: sharepoint, directory, workflow-activity

Has anybody ever written code to return the GUID of a folder in SharePoint Workflow Activity so I can then pass it into a Workflow Variable?

Would be really keen to see a code sample if you have one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, and I can offer a few tips. I didn't find code samples, so I copied code from SharePoint's DLLs using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

```
File: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\ISAPI\microsoft.sharepoint.WorkflowActions.dll
Class (for example): Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WaitForActivity
```

You'll find three properties and `DependencyProperty`s:

```
[Browsable(true), ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
public WorkflowContext __Context
{
    get { return (WorkflowContext)base.GetValue(__ContextProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(__ContextProperty, value); }
}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), Browsable(true), ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required)]
public string __ListId
{
    get { return (string)base.GetValue(__ListIdProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(__ListIdProperty, value); }
}

[Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required)]
public int __ListItem
{
    get { return (int)base.GetValue(__ListItemProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(__ListItemProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty __ContextProperty;
public static DependencyProperty __ListIdProperty;
public static DependencyProperty __ListItemProperty;
```

And this in a static constructor:

```
static MyActivity()
{
    __ContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("__Context", typeof(WorkflowContext), typeof(MyActivity));
    __ListIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("__ListId", typeof(string), typeof(MyActivity));
    __ListItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("__ListItem", typeof(int), typeof(MyActivity));
}
```

Bind them on your `actions` file:

```
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In"/>
    <Parameter Name="__ListId" Type="System.String, mscorlib, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
    <Parameter Name="__ListItem" Type="System.Int32, mscorlib, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
  </Parameters>
```

This can be copied from the file

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow\WSS.ACTIONS
```

Then, it sould be relatively easy to get the GUID, and return it using a property and out parameter binding.